# Change a custom post type on an existing site

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a site using two custom post types called destination and walk, where destination is used to categorise walks, by pulling a list of destinations into the walk editor.

Part of the site has now been spun out into it own site dealing with cycling holidays exclusively, but the walk slug is still present in the urls, which is obviously inappropriate.

Does anyone know if and how I can change the url slug for the custom post type without completely busting 90% of the links on the site?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can change the url slug by searching for the custom post type where it is created i.e register_post_type and change the slug parameter value to whatever you like.You can follow the following steps..

Locate and replace post type slug with any slug you need, try not to use spaces.

1) Just search for slug you need to update.

The script should look like:

'slug' => 'walk'

2) Save the file and test your website.

3) Sometimes you may get 404 error after changing custom post type slug, it is related to permalinks issue. You need to open admin panel, change permalinks structure to default, save website and then revert it to previous state.